# How do we solve $ (e^{x^2/4} f'(x))' = e^{x^2/4} f(x)$? -- SOLVED

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How do we solve

> $$(e^{x^2/4} f'(x))' = e^{x^2/4} f(x)$$ $x>0$

subject to $f(x) \to 0$ as $x \to \infty$ and $f(0) = 1$?

I have no idea how to attack this really, it doesn't look like it will yield to separation of variables or to any other method that I know.

---

**EDIT**

I know how to do this now, you need to differentiate the equation twice and then things get nice. I'd delete the question if an answer hadn't already been posted.

Comment: One way of solving $y''+a(x)y'+b(x)y=0$ is by writing $u=y$ and $v=y'$, creating the linear first-order system $$\begin{pmatrix}u \\ v\end{pmatrix}'=\begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 \\ -b(x) & -a(x)\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}u \\ v\end{pmatrix},$$ which can be solved exactly using the matrix exponential.

Comment: To solve that with matrix exponentials, don't you need to know that the matrix commutes with itself when evaluated at any two time points?  Is that clear here?  I'm not seeing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Differentiate the left hand side.  Cancelling the exponentials, we get $f'' + 2xf'-f = 0$.  Solve this using power series.

Comment: Shouldn't there be a minus sign on $f$?

Comment: sorry, I made a mistake in the initial question. I have corrected myself now. I will try power series anyway, though. I was looking for a closed form solution if there is one, however.

Comment: Oops ya, should be a minus sign, but the question has been edited anyways, so this answer seems to no longer be valid?

Comment: Yes, it's not really valid anymore, thank you anyway.